# NAudio PlaybackState always Playing

Tags: naudio, playback

I have this bit of code in a .NET console application to play a recorded sound-check using NAudio:

```
    static void Play(int outputDeviceIndex, byte[][] recordedChunks)
    {
        using (var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent())
        {
            waveOut.DeviceNumber = outputDeviceIndex;
            waveOut.PlaybackStopped += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Playback stopped: " + args.Exception);

            var bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 1));
            waveOut.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
            waveOut.Play();
            
            foreach (var chunk in recordedChunks)
            {
                bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
            }

            while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

The recorded sound (in recordedChunks) plays back, but neither the while loop terminates nor is the waveOut.PlaybackStopped callback activated.

Have tried this:

using (var waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))

but it seems to fail for me as the original code above.

What is wrong with this? All help appreciated. (And also, oddly, I thought this worked last week, but now it doesn't? Perhaps I am mistaken!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BufferedWaveProvider` is a never-ending stream. It always provides audio to read even if that is silent. So playback will never end.

You can change this by setting the `ReadFully` property to `false`. But you will also need to change your code above to write into the `BufferedWaveProvider` before you start playing.

Also `BufferedWaveProvider` uses a circular buffer behind the scenes. It is intended for situations where audio is being added in real-time. So be careful not to overflow the buffer if you're adding everything in one go.